# Canvas Painting Over with Apha Value

Tags: javascript, canvas, shader, opacity, alpha

A red rectangle, that I've drawn should smoothly disappear.
As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/T64ap/1/), it works, but it does not completely disappear. Why?

```
(function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'), ctx;
    if (!canvas.getContext) return;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.1)";
    setInterval(function() {        
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.fill();
    }, 100);
}());
```

It should also do the job with lots of different colors and alpha values at the same time.

Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to rounding errors in canvas. The value when multiplied with the alpha channel will have to cut the fraction to fit the integer nature of the bitmap.

In all cases here the value will never become full alpha.

The work-around is to track the current alpha level and at the last one clear manually.

**[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/T64ap/2/)**

```
var tracker = 0,
    timer;

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.1)";
timer = setInterval(function() {        
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.fill();
    tracker++;
    if (tracker > 43) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. I can't use the work-around, because there are lots of objects with different alpha values on the canvas.

Comment: @ChristophBühler just embed each rectangle with color and tracker in an object which self-update. Then spawn the different rectangles and update them all in the same loop (single timer). That will allow you to just focus on a single object.

Comment: It's not about rectangles. I am using this for a shading purpose. The performance loss would be too huge to track all these dynamic pixels.